# how to detect bullet hit in space invaders console game with lncurses

Tags: c, cygwin, curses

How would I complete this function to make the bullet destroy a rock (displayed by a # character)? I was thinking of using mvinch to check if the * bullet character == "#", but that's not working.

```
void update_bullet(int key_code) {
    screen_position bullet_pos = get_sprite_screen_loc(bullet_id);
    if (bullet_pos.x < 0 && key_code == ' ') {
        screen_position ship_pos = get_sprite_screen_loc(ship_id);
        move_sprite_to(bullet_id, ship_pos.x + 7, ship_pos.y + 3);
    } else if (bullet_pos.x > 79) {
        move_sprite_to(bullet_id, -1, 0);
    } else if (bullet_pos.x > 0) {
        move_sprite(bullet_id, 1, 0);
    }
}
```

What the code above does is move the bullet across the screen.

What i was trying to make it do is when it goes outside to the edge of the console screen, it moves back to (-1,0), and when it is in the same position as a rock #, both the # and * character moves back to (-1,0).

Answer (score 0):

You can't move the cursor out of the window, so your `move_sprite` function (which was not given in the question) has to handle that aspect.  For instance (lacking the code for `move_sprite`, it might be doing

```
int move_sprite(screen_position position, int dx, int dy)
{
    int y, x;
    getyx(stdscr, y, x);
    if (dx > 0) {
        ++x;
    }
    else if (dx < 0) {
        x = -1;             /* this is incorrect, but matches the information given in the question */
    }
    ...
    move(y, x);
}
```

According to the [`move`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_move.3x.html) manual page, an attempt to move the cursor out of the window will return `ERR` and have no effect.

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: It answered the issue provided by the information given.